# How to print a range of numeric values without using a loop, recursion or goto statement?

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers

I found this solution from internet but I am unable to understand it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n = 0;

void first() {
    void* x;
    printf("%d\n", ++n);
    if (n >= 100) {
        exit(0);
    }   
    *((char**) (&x + 4)) -= 5;
}

int main() {
    first();
    return 1;
}
```

What is the purpose and mechanism of this statement: `*((char**) (&x + 4)) -= 5;`?

Are there any other approaches that are less convoluted?

Comment: This is a hackish junk code, using an obfuscated recursion by modifying the return value in a stack.

Comment: Looks like UB City....

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. Forget it. Where did you find it?

Comment: but why forget it?

Comment: Because if you write such a code for production, you will get fired right away. Maybe even shot.

Comment: @zulqadaridrishi Because you should avoid Undefined Behavior like the plague.

Comment: "but why forget it?" - because this code only does what you say **by very small chance**. It is not valid C code. Writing such code in y company is a good way to get fired pretty soon.

Comment: [Your code breaks on the first compiler I've tried](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/444bedb6ea1b41f2). That's why you should not rely on undefined behaviour.

Comment: In short, UB is behavior that might seem to work in your case very well, but it might break unexpectedly depending on your OS, your compiler, the CPU architecture you target, and even the context within the code. If your function gets optimized it can produce unexpected results or crash the whole program, because that's where most UB breaks.

Comment: Is this a real exercise that's supposed to teach you something useful, or some sort of online competition where you're supposed to amaze each other with obscure tricks?

Answer (score 9):

The "trick" is in

```
*((char**) (&x + 4)) -= 5;
```

This is changing the memory 4 bytes beyond where `x` is stored and decreasing it by 5.

Assuming this code works for you, it's changing the return address of the function, presumably so that instead of  returning to main at the line

```
return 1
```

it instead returns to the line

```
first();
```

That is, it's relying on knowledge of your processor, stack frame layout, and your compiler's output to synthesize something that's a lot like a goto statement.

So, rewriting

```
*((char**) (&x + 4)) -= 5;
```

in english it'd look like "change where I return to be one statement earlier."
This is a gimmick rather than something you can depend on in the future.

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour. That's all to be said!

Comment: @Olaf In terms of whether "should I do something like that," "undefined behavior," is the end of the story.  However in terms of understanding how computers work, we can say a lot more

Comment: Technically, a goto statement.

Comment: That is not about "how computers work", but about "why does **my** computer for this **specific** compiler with a **specific** version **specific** settings on a **specific** day, … (got it?) does that. Worse: OP did not even say the code does what he thinks. He only repeats what someone else wrote - or not.

Comment: @bluejack: Technically plain rubbish. Can't warn about such stuff often enough apparently with people still trying to make sense of tealeaves.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such solution. Almost anything you can think of executes a loop. Even `puts` internally loops over the strings - so even if you included the desired output in the code, the `puts` does looping. Heck, most C runtime libraries will execute loops to preinitialize the memory, etc.

But let's assume that implicit looping is allowable - i.e. that you can't write any loops, but loops within library functions that you call are allowed.

Then the most naive solution is to include the desired output in the code. E.g. use awk to generate the string, then print it out:

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "\""; for (i=0; i<=100; i++) printf i"\\n"; printf "\""}'
```

Thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char output[] = "0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n41\n42\n43\n44\n45\n46\n47\n48\n49\n50\n51\n52\n53\n54\n55\n56\n57\n58\n59\n60\n61\n62\n63\n64\n65\n66\n67\n68\n69\n70\n71\n72\n73\n74\n75\n76\n77\n78\n79\n80\n81\n82\n83\n84\n85\n86\n87\n88\n89\n90\n91\n92\n93\n94\n95\n96\n97\n98\n99\n100\n";

int main(void) {
  puts(output);
}
```

The output will consist of all numbers between 0 and 100, each on its own line:

```
0
1
[...]
99
100
```

Now let's think of how to rewrite the hack you offered in the question without undefined behavior. We could use `setjmp` and `longjmp` - they are the nonlocal goto, after all. See [`setjmp` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/setjmp) for details and for the code I modified below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdnoreturn.h>

jmp_buf jump_buffer;

noreturn void a(int count)
{
   printf("%d\n", count);
   longjmp(jump_buffer, count+1); // will return count+1 out of setjmp
}

int main(void)
{
   volatile int count = 0; // modified local vars in setjmp scope must be volatile
   if (setjmp(jump_buffer) != 101) // compare against constant in an if
      a(count++);
}
```

This produces the same output as above, and invokes no undefined behavior.

Yet another way to recurse, without undefined behavior, is to use library functions that indirectly call your function via a function pointer. E.g. `bsearch`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void call();

int comp(const void * lhs, const void * rhs) {
   static volatile int count;
   if (count <= 100)
      printf("%d\n", count++);
   if (count <= 100)
      call();
   return (int*)lhs < (int*)rhs ? -1 : 1;
}

void call() {
   static const int array[] = {0, 1};
   static int key = 0;
   bsearch(&key, array, 2, sizeof(array[0]), comp);
}

int main(void) {
   call();
}
```

On a POSIX platform, `raise` invoked within a signal handler is legal, and thus you could have a variation of the above using signals - `raise` effectively recurses into `a`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void a(int signal)
{
   static volatile int count;
   printf("%d\n", count++);
   if (count <= 100)
      raise(SIGTERM);
}

int main(void)
{
   signal(SIGTERM, a);
   raise(SIGTERM);
}
```

Another solution for implicit recursion would use `atexit`. You'd need to consult the C standard to check whether calling `atexit` from within an exit handler is allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print() {
   static int count;
   printf("%d\n", count);
   if (count++ < 100)
      atexit(print);
}

int main(void)
{
   atexit(print);
}
```

Perhaps we could use recursion, but not inside the process, but outside of it - we could invoke our process repeatedly using the `system` call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int count = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;
   printf("%d\n", count);
   fflush(stdout);
   if (count >= 100) return 0;
   int len = strlen(argv[0])+10;
   char * buf = malloc(len);
   if (!buf) return 1;
   int num = snprintf(buf, len, "\"%s\" %u", argv[0], count+1);
   if (num < len)
      system(buf);
}
```